# getting json values in html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, typescript

- I am trying to access the json values {{u.login}} from html
- right now I am able to access through js
- is it possible to access through html
- right now I am getting as text
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below

```html
<span>testing json value{{u.login}}</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/obqzq7o0/

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
        Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users'))
                .subscribe(users => {
                    console.log('users ready', users);

                    $('.tiger-leather').hide();
                    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            data: users.map(function (u)  { return ({ FileName: u.login }) }),
```

Comment: this isnt angular....

Answer (score 0):

Typically you can't. Html will not know which json need to map in. You will need the help from javascript.

Another way is using external library, like [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/#demo) . Look at their demo, I think it's what you prefer

Comment: I updated with mustach but still not working http://jsfiddle.net/qeq5kqhj/